# CLLocationManager Delegate changes in iPhone OS 4.0

Tags: iphone

I have to run my app using iPhone OS 4.0. but while I am running my app  the   CLLocationManager delegate is not getting called.

The delegate method is

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
}
```

Comment: oh god, please somebody reformat this... I have the same issue, This was my first google search link, I'm going to keep searching.

Comment: Couldn't find anything on this dude. Sorry, I had to ask something similar since I can't edit your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040796/why-does-cllocationmanager-returns-null-locations-on-the-iphone-sdk-4-beta-in-the

Answer (score 0):

I can probably help, as I've been dealing with CLLocationManager successfully on iOS4 on a 3GS device, but I need more information.

1) Did you alloc/init the `CLLocationManager` previously and call `startUpdatingLocation`?  Please include that code, we may be able to help.  Specifically, where/how you are setting the delegate?  Also, make sure someone is retaining your delegate class so that way you're able to receive the calls.  CLLocationManager will not retain the delegate.

2) Are you testing on a device, or on the Simulator?  If you are testing on a device, which device?