# Why does CLLocationManager returns null locations on the iphone SDK 4 beta in the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, cllocationmanager, ios4

I have this piece of code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Manager did update location!!");
    self.currentLocation = newLocation.description;
}
```

I have this code inside a class that conforms to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. I tested earlier in sdk 3.0 and works nice (on both simulator and device). I'm testing this class on the SDK 4, in the simulator, but it gives `null` as a newLocation. I can't even get the NSLog for the first call. I checked other app where I use the location framework and it doesn't work either.

I implemented the `locationManager:didFailWithError:` message also, wich is never called.

Can anyone please confirm that the simulator can't do any CLLocationManager capabilities? (a link where the bug is reported as a known issue will be awesome). Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

-Update: I tested this on the new SDK4 GM release and still doesn't work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't discuss the SDK 4 outside of the Apple developer site until it is out of beta and released to the public.