# MapKit/CoreLocation/ShowsUserLocation implementation strategy

Tags: ios, ios4, mkmapview, core-location, mkannotation

I'm implementing a map in one of my apps, the user's location needs to be read and then the map zoomed to current location and then pins added for businesses surrounding the user.

I've got it working to a point but i'm confused as to how to implement the current location stuff.

I tried adding a `MKMapView` and setting `showsUserLocation = YES` which in the simulator will always annoyingly place you at Apple's HQ in CA, no good to me for testing!

So, I thought i'd implement `CoreLocation` which works brilliantly and in the simulator, uses the network/WiFi mapping to figure out that i'm at home and returns lat/long for my home.

However, so far, I can only represent the current location with a `MKPinAnnotationView` setting it to a green dot.  This animates nicely onto my map but what i'd really like though is to have the blue dot as my current location annotation with the circle around it similar to `showsUserLocation`.

Is there a way in a delegate protocol for `MKMapView` to intercept how the `showsUserLocation = YES` internals work to accomplish this?  Or, can I reset the co-ordinates that it thinks are right to display my actual location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator is displaying the Apple's HQ because it doesn't have a GPS chip available.
I'd recommend to test your code on a device and use showUserLocation = YES in order to show the user's current location.

The hack you are trying to do is not recommended.

Comment: No problem, what about doing a simulator discovery and punching some co-ordinates in manually, I can do on-device testing as i'm a paid up developer just wondered if there was a way to do it in simulator.

Comment: Alternatively, in the viewDidLoad, how about detect simulator and use CL/MKPinAnnotation as a temprary method but if not in simulator, use showsUserLocation=YES and then manage the request for getting the surrounding businesses from the back end server through the delegate function mapView:didUpdateUserLocation?

Comment: i tried a similar solution, detecting if i was on the simulator and punching coordinates manually but there where some problems with the CLLocationManager it always returned null  locations in the simulator.(similar problem to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040796/why-does-cllocationmanager-returns-null-locations-on-the-iphone-sdk-4-beta-in-the) => the didUpdateUserLocation wasn't called.

Comment: Thanks SorinA.  Hmmm, they must have changed it since iOS 4.2 (never tried it on early 4.x) as CLLocationManager now gives decent coordinates, for me, didUpdateUserLocation does get called and I use it to set the region and span as per another post on SO.

Comment: The real world solution to this was to ignore the blue circle when running in simulator, ie, i set showsUserLocation=YES and then monitor didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation after calling [CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation].  I discovered another post on SO that explained that CLLocationManager is used by showsUserLocation anyway and the device is intelligent enough to only run one instance of the GPS tech, therefore, it messages all interested delegates with new locations although your blue dot doesn't move in simulator, you do get location updates correctly and can populate/zoom your map.